# Вход в аккаунт на сайте через requests python

Tags: python, сессия, requests, аутентификация

Я использую requests python для входа в аккаунт на сайте. Я нашел, что нужно создать сессию, в ней сделать post с логином и паролем и в этой же сессии сделать нужный мне зарос get, так? Но где мне найти информацию, в каком виде передать эти логин и пароль. Я пробовал так:

```
s = requests.Session()
datas = {'login': lst[0], 'password': lst[1]}
url = 'https://elschool.ru/logon/index'
loging = s.post(url, data=datas)
```

Но когда я делаю новый запрос:

```
url = 'https://elschool.ru/users/diaries/details?RooId=18&InstituteId=112&DepartmentId=115968&PupilId=141652&Year=2020&Week=40&log=False'
page = s.get(url)
```

то он не авторизируется. И меня перебрасывает на страницу, где нужно заново пробовать войти. Что я сделал не так? Подскажите, просто еще не сталкивался с такими вещами)

Comment: Не совсем понял. В вопросе написано, что надо сделать get-запрос, а в примере post?

Comment: Извините, ошибся. Но все равно не работает никак

Comment: Если повторите в точности запросы от браузера, получите положительный результат. Возможно, после запроса авторизации нужно было заполнить какие-то заголовки запроса. Используйте этот код, чтобы видеть какие запросы отправляет `requests`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a7bbd36ba26faa7ade03ffc32d0b5da75a90c53d/requests__examples/view_raw_request.py#L10

Comment: Я получил кучу непонятных мне слов:) Что они означают?

Comment: `DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): elschool.ru:443
send: b'POST /logon/index HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: elschool.ru\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.24.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 93\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n'
send: b'login=%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%90%D0%94&password=1598753QqQq'
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://elschool.ru:443 "POST /logon/index HTTP/1.1" 302 137
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'`

Comment: `reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'`

Comment: В куках при входе в аккаунт создается JWToken. Он может как-то помочь дальше отправлять get запрос?